# Creating a block that lists various posts for various categories

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I need to achieve something like this:

[image]

This is a block on a page. Stuff like U.S., Politics, World etc. are the categories (created by adding a custom vocabulary) and the sub-links are articles under those categories. I'm using Drupal 7.8 and have the Views module installed.

Maybe I could write some PHP code and save as a block and then add that to a region. If so, which functions would I need?

Answer (score 1):

Views are you friend. A View can also generate a Block. The sub-links are categories ordered by publishing date? Fairly easy.

Comment: Could you please elaborate. I'm fairly new to Drupal

Comment: Take a look at the Views Documentation and Screencasts (Google it). With Views you can do a lot of things. In your case render three articles for each Category.
https://drupal.org/project/views
The documentation for Views 3 Drupal 7 is contained within Views module! Install the Advanced Help module to access it.
https://drupal.org/project/advanced_help